# How can I generate an intentional DC spike voltage?

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, spike

I have a 24 VDC circuit which uses a photocell to detect the level of fluid in a tank.  When the level drops, this operates a 24 VDC, 1 A fluid solenoid which refills the tank. It works fine with water.  The problem is, the actual fluid is very thick and as such the solenoid fails to open.

The common way to overcome this is to initially spike the solenoid with 48 V for between 10 - 100 ms and then drop to 24 VDC to hold the solenoid open for the rest of the fill time.

How do I generate a 48 VDC timed spike to the solenoid? How can I do it without affecting the rest of the circuitry? (Photocell, LEDs, etc.)

Comment: Welcome! My first choice to do something like that would be an MCU, but there are many other possibilities, a 555, a one-shot timer like CD4060 and so on. But if we are talking relays anyway, how about a time lag relay and a SPDT relay to switch between 24 and 48 V?

Comment: I would recommend you choose the right solenoid/valve combination for the fluids and pressure involved or it will just come back to bite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified schematic. The time lag relay needs to turn on for 10-100 ms and then go off whenever your control signal goes high. 10 ms may be too short for electromechanical relays.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRSFWq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>